# Observer implementation in JSP

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, observer-pattern

I have such a problem with implementation design pattern. I've some class which keeps guard in my project, is observerManager and also some observers in jsp pages. Observers will be waiting for notify from observerManager(when user add some information or change something, run notifyChanged in observerManager).  These class were implemented by now. 
My bigest problem is how to use these.

```
 public class ObserverManagerImp implements ObserverManager{
        private LinkedList<Observer> observers; 

    private User user;
    private ActionDone action;

    public ObserverManagerImp() {
        observers = new LinkedList<Observer>();
    }

    @Override
    public void registerObserver(Observer observer) {
        observers.add(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterObserver(Observer observer) {
        observers.remove(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyObservers() {
        for(Observer observer : observers)
            observer.update(user,action);

    }

    public void dataChanged(User user, ActionDone action){
        this.user= user; 
        this.action = action;
        notifyObservers();
    }
}
```

Interface observer. In this place(in update method) I'd like to run jquery function to show up content from jsp.

```
   public interface Observer {
        public void update(User user, ActionDone action);
    }
```

In JSP file is some box written in html and I would like to pop up it when the observerManager notify that.

```
<div id="message_content">
<div class="title" >Notification</div>
<div class="close" ><img id="close_button" src="images/close.png" id="close_button" width="25" height="25"/></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="message">User: name surname, added new comment</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<button id="close_button" class="close_button" >Refresh Panel</button>
</div>
```

And javascript function in this jsp:

```
function showUp(userName, userSurname, actionCode){
        $("#message_content.message").empty().append("User: " + userName + " " + userSurname + "was " + actionCode);
        $("#message_content").show();
    }
```

And in this jsp I also create a object which is observer. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trying the ServletRequestAttributeListener , you will be able to monitor the changes in request attributes.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequestAttributeListener.html